# Launching adhoc job in DJCelery Django Celery Admin view

Tags: celery, django-celery

Unless I am missing something obvious, DJCelery the Django admin for celery doesn't allow for a mechanism for a user to launch an adhoc job which seems to be a very useful functionality to allow backend users to launch jobs on a need basis...If this is just missing, would a patch be accepted for it, since it would almost be trivial to implement?

Config: Celery 3.0.21 with Django 1.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on discussions with asksol, currently there is no support in the admin for this..Outlining a process which will hopefully soon be contributed back to the repo.

- Define a custom admin for periodic tasks
- Add a custom form to the admin, with an additional boolean field for adhoc execution
- In the form clean catch the adhoc execution flag from the form, launch the background process and remove flag field from the form